# fade out the screen?

Tags: android, screen, splash-screen, fadeout

I'm making a splash screen in the application that I'm developing for the android platform. My question is, how can I fade out the splash screen or any screen? Or can I add effects? like the new screen is coming from above? Or using a picture to float over the screen and the other screen is behind it? like effects in video edditing? Is it even possible? I think I saw something like that in some iphone apps. By the way I am using gl. I'm pretty new so can you be specific? Please help me! Thanks!